# Can't configure Socketio: TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to a simple token authorization for socketio as outlined in their [docs](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing). But node throws:

```
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'
```

when I try to configure socketio with `io.configure`. Any idea why the configuration method wouldn't be available?

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').Server(app)
  , io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.configure(function (){
  io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    ...
})
```

Full stacktrace:

```
/Users/administrator/dev/chat-example/lib/io.js:9
  io.configure(function (){
     ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'configure'
    at module.exports (/Users/administrator/dev/chat-example/lib/io.js:9:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/administrator/dev/chat-example/app.js:4:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: The docs are apparently not up-to-date with respect to `io.configure()`. The method [was defined](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/0.9.17/lib/manager.js#L266-L274) for Socket.IO 0.9 and older, but [appears to have been removed](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/1.0.0/lib/index.js) in the rewrite for 1.0 and later.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thats a shame, any idea how to configure socketio then?

Comment: [`io.use()`](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace) will let you add custom middleware, like checking authorization. And, `io.set()` [still exists](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/1.2.1/lib/index.js#L109-L135), apparently just for compatibility. Its definition shows an example of using `io.use()`.

Comment: Is there a difference between `io.configure` and `io.use`?

Comment: opened github issue: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

io.configure and io.set are being deprecated. Here is a sample middleware for socket.io 1.x

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var handshake = socket.request;

    if (!handshake) {
        return next(new Error('[[error:not-authorized]]'));
    }

    cookieParser(handshake, {}, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        var sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['express.sid'];

        db.sessionStore.get(sessionID, function(err, sessionData) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            console.log(sessionData);

            next();
        });
    });
});
```